# Why is Visio expanding the size of the page?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Why does Visio expand the drawing area when pasting shape on a page? I can copyt everything which fits on one printing page area, paste it on a new page and it creates two printing pages.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwDeE.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off **Auto Size** in the **Design** tab should help.

[image]

Comment: Please note that Visio isn't adding a page, it is expanding the size of the current page. I hope you don't mind if I correct your question.